# APNS iOS Push works from desktop, but not from web server

Tags: apache, apple-push-notifications

I have used a tutorial (http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1) to try to get push notifications working for an app I'm making.

Using MAMP (i.e. my desktop's local server) the php runs, connects, and sends the push perfectly.

When I move the ck.pem file and my php file to a web server, I get the error message: **Failed to connect: 0**

I'm not great with server admin, and thus have no clue as to why my local apache server works, while another in-house web server does not.